# Unity Facebook auto-logging app event not working properly

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, in-app-events

We're making a game in Unity, and we're using the FacebookSDK.
We are currently experiencing an issue with App Events.
Auto Logging App Event is checked in Facebook Setting.
App activation and deactivation, and fb_sdk_settings_changed events work properly. However, the in-app purchase event does not come.
When I searched the community, I saw two answers saying no.

[link](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/538649833819365/?__cft__%5B0%5D=AZW5TjABVNf1SD-ShXZ91YzuSbaaXVNJehgg_jMTyWg9sy22K-Qtb6lxyeu2x3dmC-ElJ8Hs7oVwzIi9KwGyjFspHeaPVcvXAl6_wFoCwGKYkxzSyxk82pqBz8E3hGTXAwDuUOY3QQnMN2pk1ID4KTIbVS45JxTr_JM66DNX18vL4A93VkdJPIliWl6wJRrJi98&__tn__=-UK-R)
[link2](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/620469585868445/?__cft__%5B0%5D=AZW5TjABVNf1SD-ShXZ91YzuSbaaXVNJehgg_jMTyWg9sy22K-Qtb6lxyeu2x3dmC-ElJ8Hs7oVwzIi9KwGyjFspHeaPVcvXAl6_wFoCwGKYkxzSyxk82pqBz8E3hGTXAwDuUOY3QQnMN2pk1ID4KTIbVS45JxTr_JM66DNX18vL4A93VkdJPIliWl6wJRrJi98&__tn__=-UK-R)

I read an article that said it was measured but had different issues.

[link](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/818027128772353/?__cft__%5B0%5D=AZW5TjABVNf1SD-ShXZ91YzuSbaaXVNJehgg_jMTyWg9sy22K-Qtb6lxyeu2x3dmC-ElJ8Hs7oVwzIi9KwGyjFspHeaPVcvXAl6_wFoCwGKYkxzSyxk82pqBz8E3hGTXAwDuUOY3QQnMN2pk1ID4KTIbVS45JxTr_JM66DNX18vL4A93VkdJPIliWl6wJRrJi98&__tn__=-UK-R)

Other than that, I couldn't find any additional answers that helped me.
Do you know if there is any special work to be done?

Unity 2021.3.8 , Facebook Unity SDK 11.0.0